# Calculating correlation coefficient

Tags: r, correlation, covariance

```
a <- c(10,11)
b <- c(2,3)
```

The covariance (`C`) between`a` and `b` =

```
sum ( (a-mean(a)) * (b-mean(b)) ) # equal to  cov(a,b) in this case as n=2
```

The sample covariance (`Csamp`) between`a` and `b` =

```
sum ( (a-mean(a)) * (b-mean(b)) ) / n-1 # equal to  cov(a,b)
```

Now lets say the sum of square differences for `a` = `SSa`. This means the Variance(`V`) for `a` = `SSa/n` and the sample variance(`Vsamp`) is `SSa/n-1`. The sample standard deviation (`SDsamp`) for `a` would be `sqrt(SSa/n-1)`

The correlation coeffictent equations as I have found it are:

```
(1) C  /  sqrt(SSa) * sqrt(SSb)

# or

(2)  C  /  SDsamp_a * SDsamp_b

# (1) uses sqrt(SSa), not V or V samp and (2) uses SDsamp  not V and does not use Csamp
```

I am confused over how to calculate the correlation coefficient (`CF`) and the sample correlation coefficient (`CFsamp`). The two formulas above do not seem the same to me. can someone explain how to calculate `CF` and `CFsamp`?

Comment: From `help("cov")`: "The denominator n - 1 is used which gives an unbiased estimator of the (co)variance for i.i.d. observations." So, `cov(a,b)` actually calculates the sample covariance.

Comment: @Roland yes I saw that thanks but in this case `C` and `Csamp` are not different as `n=2`, ill edit to make clearer

Comment: You need to divide the covariance by n if you don't estimate the means. So, `C` is the covariance multiplied by n.  And if you consider that 2-1=1 there is no difference between `SSa`  and `SDsamp_a`  in your example.

Comment: "divide the covariance by n if you don't estimate the means (i.e., your C)" not sure what you mean here sorry?

Comment: The population covariance is your `C` divided by n.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pearson product correlation coefficient is defined as:

$$r=\frac{cov(X,Y)}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y}.$$

In order to estimate it from the sample, you put in the sample estimates of covariance and standard deviation:

$$r=\frac{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum{(X_i-\bar{X})(Y_i-\bar{Y})}}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum(X_i-\bar{X})^2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1}\sum(Y_i-\bar{Y})^2}}$$

Fortunately, $n-1$ is cancelled out and you get

$$r=\frac{\sum{(X_i-\bar{X})(Y_i-\bar{Y})}}{\sqrt{\sum(X_i-\bar{X})^2}\sqrt{\sum(Y_i-\bar{Y})^2}}$$

Due to this last step it doesn't matter for the correlation coefficient if you divide by $n$ or by $(n-1)$ when calculating the covariance and standard deviations.

Comment: thanks, the papers I had added to my confusion by not being explicit between Sample and population estimates. However realising the cancellation of n or n-1 respectively makes everything clear.

Comment: Sorry, not able to comment. Very clear answer. I think the second $\sqrt{\Sigma (X_i - \bar X)^2}$ was meant to be $\sqrt{\Sigma (Y_i - \bar Y)^2}$.

Comment: @pentandrous Thanks. TeX is nice, but it's easy to get lost in the formula syntax.